# Проблемы с кодировкой в составном print (Python 2, Anaconda Jupypter, Win 10)

Tags: python, кодировка, print

Код такой:

```
list= ['Сергей','Василий'] 

print(list[0])

print(list[0],'и',list[1])
```

Выводит:

> Сергей
>
> ('\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9', '\xd0\xb8',
>   '\xd0\x92\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9')

Что сделать, чтобы второй `print` выводил так же, как и первый (в нормальной кодировке)?

Answer (score 1):

```
list= ['Сергей','Василий']

print(list[0])

print(list[0] + ' и ' + list[1])
```

или

```
list= ['Сергей','Василий']

print(list[0])

print list[0], 'и', list[1]
```

Comment: @Кирилл_Малышев

А с таким похожим случаем подскажете? Как побороть кодировку во втором print? (Поставил __ там где перевод строки)

dict = {'Мороженое':[{'Тип':'Пломбир', 'Цена':256}, __

                      {'Тип':'Эскимо', 'Цена':221}]} __

print dict['Мороженое'][0]['Тип'] __

print dict['Мороженое'][0] #обращение по ключу Словаря __

Пломбир __

{'\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbf': '\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80', '\xd0\xa6\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0': 256}